# Glitchy animation CAAnimation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, caanimation, stroke

I am trying to create a new imageview which is going to have an animation feature. But, I have a problem about my animation, lets see;

[image: Glitchy animation]

Here, all I need is to make this animation seems continuous. I mean, without that glitch at the beginning of every loop. Just right edge of the corner at top left.

Here are my animations;

```
let strokeEndAnimation: CAAnimation = {
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = 1
    animation.duration = 2

    let group = CAAnimationGroup()
    group.duration = 2.3
    group.repeatCount = .infinity
    group.animations = [animation]

    return group
}()

let strokeStartAnimation: CAAnimation = {
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeStart")
    animation.beginTime = 0.3
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = 1
    animation.duration = 2

    let group = CAAnimationGroup()
    group.duration = 2.3
    group.repeatCount = .infinity
    group.animations = [animation]

    return group
}()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't simply achieve it with a standard closed path and `strokeStart` + `strokeEnd`, because these value are `Float` lies between `0.0` and `1.0`, however you can play some tricks on the path itself.

I'll take a circular path for example since it's more straight-forward.

```
// Create an arc path with 2.353π (animation start at 0.15)
let arcPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100), radius: 90.0, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(.pi * 2.353), clockwise: true)

let pathLayer = CAShapeLayer()
pathLayer.path = arcPath.cgPath
pathLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
pathLayer.fillColor = nil
pathLayer.lineWidth = 10.0

// stroke start run from 0 - 0.85 (0π - 2π)
let aniSS = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeStart")
aniSS.fromValue = 0
aniSS.toValue = 0.85
aniSS.duration = 2

// stroke end run from 0.15 - 1 (0.353π - 2.353π)
let aniSE = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
aniSE.fromValue = 0.15
aniSE.toValue = 1
aniSE.duration = 2

let group = CAAnimationGroup()
group.duration = 2
group.repeatCount = .infinity
group.animations = [aniSS, aniSE]

pathLayer.add(group, forKey: "strokeAnimation")
```

So that when an animation loop end, the stroke sit at `2π` - `2.353π` which looks exactly identical as when an animation loop start: `0π` - `0.353π`, might not be the optimized solution but it did the work.

Comment: If I do it for circular path, its ok. But I wanna do it for any view or bezierPath. My main goal is to move a line on a bezier path.

Comment: you can extend your standard bezier path just like how i extend the circular path in the example, so the first said 15% of your path is stacked, and achieve the same result by setting the `fromValue` and `toValue` like I did.

Comment: This doesn't work for a bezier path. The end of the animation does not flow smoothly into the next animation cycle.

Answer (score -1):

I know this post is 5 years old, but there still aren't any good solutions out there to solve this issue. I was able to achieve the desired result using a second layer. The main progress layer is in blue. The second layer is in red to show how it replaces the first layer, and makes it appear to be the same loader:
[image]

Here's the code:

```
- (void)animate {
  [self beginning];
  [self end];
}

- (void)beginning {
  [_progressLayer removeAllAnimations];
  CAKeyframeAnimation *animationStart = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:kStrokeStart];
  animationStart.values = @[@0, @0, @0.75];
  animationStart.keyTimes = @[@0, @0.25, @1];
  animationStart.duration = 2;
  
  CAKeyframeAnimation *animationEnd = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:kStrokeEnd];
  animationEnd.values = @[@0, @0.25, @1];
  animationEnd.keyTimes = @[@0, @0.25, @1];
  animationEnd.duration = 2;
  
  CAAnimationGroup *group = [CAAnimationGroup new];
  group.duration = 2;
  group.repeatCount = INFINITY;
  group.animations = @[animationStart, animationEnd];
  [_progressLayer addAnimation:group forKey:@"beginning"];
}

- (void)end {
  [_progressLayerTail removeAllAnimations];
  CABasicAnimation *animationStart = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:kStrokeStart];
  animationStart.fromValue = @0.75;
  animationStart.toValue = @1;
  animationStart.duration = 0.5;

  CABasicAnimation *animationEnd = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:kStrokeEnd];
  animationEnd.fromValue = @1;
  animationEnd.toValue = @1;
  animationEnd.duration = 0.5;
  
  CAAnimationGroup *group = [CAAnimationGroup new];
  group.duration = 2;
  group.repeatCount = INFINITY;
  group.animations = @[animationStart, animationEnd];
  [_progressLayerTail addAnimation:group forKey:@"end"];
}
```